# KAM theory in dynamical systems

Tags: reference-request

What is the best text/lecture notes to read if you want to learn KAM theory in Hamiltonian dynamical systems?

Comment: Not an answer, but a nice overview of the theorem: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8090633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could start with :

```
De La Llave R., 2003, A Tutorial on Kam Theory, Universi Series. American Mathematical Society
```

that you can find on numerous places on the internet. You will also find numerous relevant references therein.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you starting from? A very nice book for KAM theory is *Stable and Random Motions in Dynamical Systems*, by Jurgen Moser (Princeton University Press, Annals of Mathematics series, No. 77). It's not a textbook-style presentation, it's a monograph, but it does cover a lot of KAM theory and doesn't assume more than mathematical sophistication as a pre-requisite.